# How do I get the Rust compiler to dump out the LLVM it generates?

Tags: rust, llvm-ir

I'd like to see the LLVM that the Rust compiler generates. Even better would be to have it just dump out LLVM and stop. This could be in bitcode format or assembler text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass the formats which you want to `--emit`

e.g.

```
rustc --emit=asm,llvm-bc,llvm-ir xxx.rs
```

or

```
cargo rustc -- --emit=asm,llvm-bc,llvm-ir
```

more information please see `rustc --help`

Comment: Many thanks. I am not sure how I missed that when I ran `--help` and tried all sorts of `-C` and `-Z` options.

Comment: any way to find out where it dumps the .s file and how to show the optimized version?

Comment: How do you print out the generated rust code?

Answer (score 4):

You can manipulate the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable and then perform the build, something like

```
RUSTFLAGS="--emit=llvm-ir" cargo build
```

This is useful if you have no direct access to the build command (e.g., when you are building something like [Servo](https://github.com/servo/servo), which uses an abstracted build tool called `mach`).

I know this is more of an edge case, but I found it useful when trying to obtain an IR dump of Servo's code.

Answer (score 2):

For quick access to either the LLVM IR or x86_64 assembly, the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) (and the [alternate Playground](http://play.integer32.com/)) have "LLVM" and "ASM" buttons that call the compiler with the appropriate options.